# PHP + Ajax, JSON, HTML и SQL! Помогите создать правильный запрос к базе данных!

Tags: php, html, sql, ajax, json

Есть два файла. Файл **index2.php**:

```
<?php
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
define('DB_USER', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
define('DB_NAME', 'mysite');
 
try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host='.DB_HOST.'; dbname='.DB_NAME,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Ошибка при подключении к базе данных!';
}
 
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `poyas3`';
$result = $pdo->query($query);
$table = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
 
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Ajax и JSON</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
        $("select").bind("click", function(event) {
            ajax({'func': 1});
 
        });
        });
        function ajax(data) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'api2.php',
                type: "POST",
                data: data,
                dataType: "text",
                error: error,
                success: success
            });
        }
 
        function error() {
            alert('Ошибка при загрузке данных!');
        }
        function success(result) {
            var result = $.parseJSON(result);
            var str = '';
            for (var i in result)
                str += '<b>' + i + '</b>: ' + result[i] + '<br />';
            $('#result').empty();
            $('#result').append(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
 
 
            <p><select name="list1">
                    <option>Выберите из списка</option>
 
                    <?php foreach($table as $idx => $data) {
                        echo '<option>'.$data['title'].'</option>';
                    }?>
                </select></p>
 
    </div>
    <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
?>
```

И файл **api2.php**:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['func']) && $_POST['func'] == '1') {
 
    //$vibor = $_POST['list1'];
 
    define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
    define('DB_USER', 'root');
    define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
    define('DB_NAME', 'mysite');
    try {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST . '; dbname=' . DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, [PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);
        $query = "SELECT * FROM `poyas3` ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1";
        $result = $pdo->query($query);
        $row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        echo json_encode($row);
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Ошибка: '.$e->getMessage();
    }
}
?>
```

Если применять скрипты именно в таком виде, то результатом работы будет вывод на экран данных одной случайной строки из базы данных. В БД **poyas3** 3 поля: *id*, *title*(название часового пояса), *offset*(смещение по времени).
Нужно, чтобы при выборе часового пояса из выпадающего списка и нажатии на него на экране появлялось смещение по времени выбранного часового пояса. Пробую, по-разному, не получается. Нужно это сделать при помощи Ajax и JSON (то есть, без обновления скрипта, страницы).
Как это сделать?

Comment: что не получается-то? взять нужную строку из БД? ajax и json у вас уже есть, измените запрос к базе, добавьте условие нужное вместо rand()

Comment: На экране должны появиться данные смещения по времени (offset) в зависимости от того, какой выбор сделал пользователь в выпадающем списке (title). Например, делаю такой запрос, предварительно создав строку ($vibor = $_POST['list1'];): $query = "SELECT offset FROM `poyas3` WHERE `title` = $vibor"; Ничего при этом не выводится, пустой экран.

Comment: сейчас у вас по клику на селект в php (**$_POST**) передается только `{'func': 1}`  Не вижу, чтобы как-то что-то передавалось в `$_POST['list1']`, там по идее пусто.

Comment: попробуйте дописать: `ajax({ 'func': 1, 'list1': $("select[name=list1]").val() });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Допишите в теги `<option>` значения:

```php
echo '<option value="'.$data['id'].'">'.$data['title'].'</option>';
```

Добавьте текущее значение селекта в данные, которые передаются ajax'ом:

```
ajax({'func': 1, 'list1': $(this).val() });
```

И в запросе ищите нужную строку по **id**:

```php
// здесь, конечно, лучше обращаться хотя бы через filter_input
$selected_id = $_POST['list1'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM poyas3 WHERE id = $selected_id";
```

Comment: Спасибо, Ваш ответ помог!